# Simple string output not as expected (new line appearing)

Tags: c++, trigraphs

I have code equivalent to the following to print out a short string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  std::string s = "finished??/not finished??";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But the output is appearing across two lines and losing some characters:

```
finished  
ot finished??
```

But `/n` isn't the new line character! What's happening?

Comment: @ahenderson - '/n' is not a new line character. <g>

Answer (score 4):

In the first phase of translation (§2.2/1 of *ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)*), sequences of characters known as *trigraph sequences* are replaced with single characters.

> Trigraph sequences (2.4) are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations.

One of the trigraphs maps `??/` to `\`. After the first phase, the code is equivalent to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  std::string s = "finished\not finished??";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As a result of the preprocessing phases, `"finished\not finished??"` is parsed as a *string literal* containing the escape-sequence `\n` which represents the new line character. The outputted string is therefore: `finished<NL>ot finished??`.

To avoid this, you need to escape one of the question marks as `\?`. This gives you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  std::string s = "finished?\?/not finished??";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This avoids the `??/` being picked up as a trigraph.

Answer (score 0):

In gcc 4.1.2 I get this warning:

cd /devserv-home/rspikol/
g++ -g -o tz tz.C
tz.C:6:28: warning: trigraph ??/ ignored, use -trigraphs to enable

Compilation finished at Wed Oct  3 12:43:16

So, by default, this version of gcc is not C++ standard compliant.

@sftrabbit: In my copy of the C++ standard, the paragraph is 2.3/1